# s.nextLine() is skipped in a do loop

Tags: java

I am trying to create a program that asks the user for a student's name and asks him if the user would like to enter another user (Y/N). This program is repeated until the user enters N after a student is entered.

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    String student;
    char choice;
    Scanner s =new Scanner (System.in);

    System.out.println("Enter a student");
    student = s.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Do you want to enter an other student? (Y/N)");
    choice = s.next().charAt(0);

    switch(choice){
        case 'Y':
            do{
                System.out.println("Enter an other student");
                student = s.nextLine();
                System.out.println("Do you want to enter an other student? (Y/N)");
                choice = s.next().charAt(0);
            }while (choice == 'N');
            System.out.println("End");
            break;
        case 'N':
            System.out.println("End");
            break;
    }

}
```

In the do loop, the program doesn't wait for the user to enter another student. It justs ask the first question and then asks the second without waiting.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo Use BufferedReader

Comment: Your `while` condition should be negated - keep asking while the choice remains 'yes'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Scanner is skipping nextLine() after using next() or nextFoo()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13102045/scanner-is-skipping-nextline-after-using-next-or-nextfoo)

Answer (score 1):

The code before while loop only for the reason to have a different question for the first time. Other than that I would do it as Eugene Borisov suggested.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String student, choice;
    Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter a student");
    student = input.nextLine();
    System.out.println("Do you want to enter an other student? (Y/N)");
    choice = input.nextLine();

    while(choice.toLowerCase().equals("y")) {
        System.out.println("Enter a student");
        student = input.nextLine();
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter an other student? (Y/N)");
        choice = input.nextLine();
    }
    System.out.println("End");

}
```

Answer (score 0):

Using `next()` leaves a **newline character** in the buffer and the `nextLine()` reads it.

Replace

```java
choice = s.next().charAt(0);
```

with

```java
choice = s.nextLine().charAt(0);
```

and change the condition in **while** to :-

`while (choice != 'N');`

Answer (score 0):

Can't understand ur logic. But hope that it could be helpful:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    String student;
    char choice;
    Scanner s = new Scanner(System.in);
    do {
        System.out.println("Enter a student");
        student = s.next();
        System.out.println("Do you want to enter an other student? (Y/N)");
        choice = s.next().charAt(0);
    } while (choice != 'N');

}
```